# Install Magento on Amazon EC2 ( Error The requested URL /magento/ was not found on this server)

Tags: magento-1.9, url, server-setup, amazon-web-services

I try to install Magento 1.9.1.0 community edition (I follow these steps : http://www.comtechies.com/2014/03/how-to-install-magento-on-amazon-ec2.html ) but when I try to connect a Magento I get this error : 
Not Found
The requested URL /magento/ was not found on this server.

The folder /var/www/:

root@ip-168-30-60-81:/home/ubuntu# ls -l /var/www/
total 61208

```
    -rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    1117975 Aug 30 09:35 composer.phar  
    drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root       4096 Aug 29 18:46 html  
    drwxrwxr-x 13 ubuntu ubuntu     4096 Nov  5  2014 magento  
    -rw-r--r--  1 root   root   23822215 Nov 21  2014 magento-1.9.1.0.tar.gz  
    lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root         21 Aug 29 19:15 phpmyadmin ->     /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

The folder /var/www/html/ contains just index.html

Comment: Please show your virtual host settings. If you did not change them and want to install Magento at `/magento`, you will have to move `magento` to `html/magento`. If you want to install Magento at `/`, delete `html` and rename `magento` to `html` instead

Comment: @fschmengler Thank you, it works when I moved magento directory to html/magento

Comment: In magento did you set your base urls to "http://www.yourdomain.blah/magento/" or in apache / htaccess your default directory should change to /var/www/magento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did not change the virtual host settings and want to install Magento at `/magento`, you will have to move `magento` to `html/magento`.

If you want to install Magento at `/`, delete `html` and rename `magento` to `html` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would first check few things:

- Is apache running? Go to your public ip and check.
- Do you see the folder magento on /var/www/ ? Usually I install magento on /var/www/html.
- Did you open the port 80?

Comment: yes , Apache is running and I see the folder magento on /var/www/